# Why is Zero not a Critical Point of $f(x) = (x^2-63)e^{-x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find out why zero is not a critical point of $f(x) = (x^2-63)e^{-x}$. The derivative (using the product rule) is $-e^{-x}(x-9)(x+7)$. So, I know that 9 and -7 are critical points because of the $(x-9)(x+7)$, but what about the $-e^{-x}$? Shouldn't that add a critical point of $0$?

Comment: Is $e^{-0}=0$? I'd say no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical points are the points where the derivative is $0$. Since you have found the derivative to be $-e^{-x}(x-9)(x+7)$, $0$ cannot be a critical point, because 
$$ -e^{-0}(0-9)(0+7) = -1\cdot (-9)\cdot 7 = 63 \ne 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=2xe^{-x}-(x^2-63)e^{-x}=-e^{-x}(x^2-2x-63)=-e^{-x}(x-9)(x+7)
$$
A product is zero if and only if one of the factor is:

1. $e^{-x}>0$ for all $x$
2. $x-9=0$ if and only if $x=9$
3. $x+7=0$ if and only if $x=-7$

Thus only $-7$ and $9$ are critical points.